# How to block unknown browsers in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I wanted to know that How to block unknown browsers in `.htaccess`? There is a Directive that can be used in `.htaccess` called `BrowserMatchNoCase` but I do not know how to work with it.

Comment: what do you mean `unknown browsers`?

Comment: Robot , spam softwares , hackers made browsers to do some action

Comment: This won't actually help you. The `User-Agent` header can be whatever the client wants to identify itself as. You're far more likely to punish innocent programs that are being truthful, because there's nothing to stop a malicious program from identifying itself as a popular web browser.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a whitelist.

However, this is a pointless endevour. While a lot of scripts and scanners, etc... will sometimes have a fake or custom created UA (user-agent), lots of the scripts these days will just mimic known UA strings, which renders just about every possible blacklist or whitelist approach pointless.